# Angular range input value changing with seconds

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, range

I have an input that looks like this and it's hooked up to a controller that's increasing the value every second. If I set value to a number the page will reflect that when it loads but it won't reflect changes that are made dynamically. Do I have to use ng-model for dynamically changing the value? What's the best way to tackle this?

```
    <div class="range">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value={{getSeconds()}}">
    </div>
```

Comment: Would you please show your controller code, including the `getSeconds()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind anything using scoped function call angular cannot keep a watch on it so the value will not be updated. You will have to change it to a property and set using `ng-model` and update the property value using angular's `$interval` passing the required interval in milliseconds.

Html

```
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="counter" />
```

JS

```
  $scope.counter = 0;
  $interval(function () {
    $scope.counter++;
  }, 1000);
```

Demo - http://plnkr.co/edit/aWdUyXWAgwra4SjMV0uq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with `$interval` to update the model value? You can also cancel interval by `cancel()`.